# Table does not fit

Tags: tables, tabularx

I created a table that does not fit the page. It's not because it's too big, it's because the table starts from the middle of the page when I export it to PDF. So even though I have half the page empty, the table is cut off. Any tips?

This is how I started it:

```
\vfill\eject
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\caption{Listing Audit Table} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}\hline\hline
<content>
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: You should use `X` instead of `l`.

Comment: That did not work :( Thanks for answering!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks, definitely will next time. In the mean time, someone was able to help me. I used 

\usepackage{rotating}\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}

and that solved everything.